# Android API Manual

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I would like to make a manual of the android APIs that can be used in other applications. For example a calender and contacts can be used in other applications. Are there more APIs like these, which can be used in other apps where these apps as standalone are complete in itself?

Please suggest where I can read about it.

Comment: Did it work out for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/package-summary.html) be what you are looking for?

You've got `AlarmClock`, `Contacts`, `Settings.System` etc.

Comment: I want to know more about these kind of apps which can be integrated with other application.....where can get more information about them??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm understanding you correctly, but perhaps you aren't really looking for an API reference so much as a reference to **Intents** which can be started/called from your app?  If so, take a look at the [Intent documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) on the developer site.  You can use an [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to launch activities from other applications, sometimes with the ability to retrieve a result using [`startActivityForResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) (such as launching the Contacts list to pick a contact, the ID for which will be returned to your app), or the ability to view or edit things like contacts or phone numbers in their respective default apps.

For example, you can create an Intent that uses the [`"ACTION_DIAL"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL) action parameter along with the data parameter `"content://contacts/people/1"` to launch the phone's Dialer with the number for a contact already filled in.  Take a look at the [Intents and Intent Filters guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) for more information that goes beyond the general API reference.

Not all of the built-in apps support every action, nor do they all support startActivityForResult (Calendar, for example, does not allow you to launch it to use it as a date or event picker if I recall correctly). So it's worth doing some research outside of the documentation too.